# Error when running vuetifyjs template

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have successfully installed a vuetifyjs template using the command

```
vue init vuetifyjs/webpack-advanced
```

it was successfully installed but when I tried to use the command `npm run dev` I had the following error message:

C:\Users\Muse\Documents\vuetify>npm run dev

> vuetify@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Muse\Documents\vuetify
>
> node build/dev-server.js
>
> fs.js:1657
>         binding.lstat(baseLong);
>
> ```
>                 ^
> ```
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Muse\Documents\vuetify\test'
>       at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1657:15)
>       at resolve (C:\Users\Muse\Documents\vuetify\build\webpack.base.conf.js:8:13)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Muse\Documents\vuetify\build\webpack.base.conf.js:35:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! vuetify@1.0.0 dev: `node build/dev-server.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the vuetify@1.0.0 dev script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-08-31T09_19_06_701Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a test folder and give it access.
It's a bug with webpack-advanced template

Answer (score 0):

Fore install your project dependencies

```
npm install -f
```

Then, make a folder named "test" in your root project

```
mkdir test
```

It's a bug caused by `vuetifyjs/webpack-advanced`